# Bootstrap Collapse Up Automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap collapse for my following code.

```css
.downloadmenu {
  width:500px;
  background-color:#7FFFD4;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
padding:60px;
  height: auto;

}

.clear {
  clear:both;
}
span {
  background-color:red;
  padding:15px;
  border-radius:10px;
  float:right;
  margin:10px;
}

span:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="downloadmenu">

<span data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#FireFoxCol">FireFox</span>
<span data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ChromeCol">Chrome</span>
<span  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#OperaCol">Opera</span>
<span data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#SafariCol">Safari</span>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="well well-sm collapse" id="FireFoxCol">
<b>Downloding FireFox...</b><br/>
<a href="...">-Download For Windows</a><br/>
<a href="...">-Download For Linux</a>
</div>

<div class="well well-sm collapse" id="ChromeCol">
<b>Downloding Chrome...</b><br/>
<a href="...">-Download For Android</a><br/>
<a href="...">-Download For BlackBerry</a>
</div>

<div class="well well-sm collapse" id="OperaCol">
<b>Downloding Opera...</b><br/>
<a href="...">-Download For Mac</a><br/>
<a href="...">-Download For IOS</a>
</div>

<div class="well well-sm collapse" id="SafariCol">
<b>Downloding Safari...</b><br/>
<a href="...">-Download For Windows Phone</a><br/>
<a href="...">-Download For Java</a>
</div>

</div>
```

When you click on the FireFox, it shows a div.

And when you click, on the Safari forexample, another div will apear, under it.

I want that, when a div is collapse down (like FireFox) and you click on another one (like Safari), the current FireFox's div collapse up, and then Safari's div collapse down ! It's just an example.

How can I do it ?

You can also check this : https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you want is called "accordion", and it's [built in to Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion). There are 2 additional things you need to make the `data-toggle="collapse"` have only 1 collapsible item open at a time. Each collapsible item shares the same parent, in this case `data-parent=".downloadmenu"`. The other thing is that the immediate child of of the parent, must be the `.panel` class...

```
<div class="downloadmenu">
    <div class="panel">
        <span data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".downloadmenu" data-target="#FireFoxCol">FireFox</span>
        <span data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".downloadmenu" data-target="#ChromeCol">Chrome</span>
        <span data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".downloadmenu" data-target="#OperaCol">Opera</span>
        <span data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".downloadmenu" data-target="#SafariCol">Safari</span>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div class="well well-sm collapse" id="FireFoxCol">
            <b>Downloding FireFox...</b>

        </div>

        <div class="well well-sm collapse" id="ChromeCol">
            <b>Downloding Chrome...</b>

        </div>

        <div class="well well-sm collapse" id="OperaCol">
            <b>Downloding Opera...</b>

        </div>

        <div class="well well-sm collapse" id="SafariCol">
            <b>Downloding Safari...</b>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo on Codeply](http://www.codeply.com/go/f3YGJnM28D)